# Product of two numbers using recursion java

Tags: java

I'm really confused in this program:

```
public static int product(int n1, int n2) {

    if (n2== 0 || n1==0) {
       return 0;
    }
      n1 += product(n1, n2 - 1);
     return n1;
}
```

Suppose i made product(3,2), then must function returns:

Sence 3>0 and 2>0 then n1= 3+ product(3,1)

Sence 3>0 and 1>0 then n1= 3+ 3+ product(3,1)

3>0 but 0==0 then return 0;
but it returns 6.

Can some one explain that ?

Comment: 3 + 3 is 6. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Follow it through in your debugger. That will make it clear.

Comment: Side note: No need to write back to `n1`. Just `return n1 + product(n1, n2 - 1);`

Comment: Yeah it returns 0 on that recurse. Since the call is resolved it goes all the way back up the stack to where you first called it and returns 6.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i saw debugger it enter block when one of them is 0 but why not returns 0?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder you said i should `return n1 + product(n1, n2 - 1);` what if n1 = 3 and n2 = 0 then it will `return 3;` do you see your problem ?

Comment: @Br.sasa it will return zero not 3.

Comment: @Br.sasa: It doesn't get there if `n2` is `0`; there's a guard before it. My point is that there's no need to write back to the `n1` argument after the guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your explanation of how the method works, but remember, since this is recursive, it ends up returning the total of all returns. Let me explain:
The first recursion returns 3 + product(3, 1). 
However, your program does not know what product(3, 1) is yet, so it must continue before returning.
The second recursion (product(3, 1)) returns 3 + product(3, 0). 
Again, your program must continue the recursion to find product(3, 0). 
The third and final recursion returns 0, as you said, but the FINAL answer goes back to the first recursion's answer, 3 + product(3, 1).
We know that product(3, 1) = 3 + product(3, 0), and product(3, 0) = 0.
So product(3, 2) = 3 + 3 + 0, which is 6. It appears in your answer that you were expecting only to receive the final recursion for an answer, but because of your return statement, it is a combination of the three.